# Proper way to build complex strings in ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

What is proper way to build complex strings in ansible?

Given this example of az cli in command module:

```
---
- name: >
    LISTDELETED {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_DATABASE }} databases
    FROM {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_SQLSERVER }} sqlserver
  command: >
    az sql db list-deleted
    --resource-group "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESOURCEGROUP }}"
    --server "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_SQLSERVER }}"
    --query "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY | default('[*]') }}"
    --output json
  register: DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESULT
```

- It needs to handle missing parameter for example if query is missing, omit `--query` parameter.
- I would like to build string ahead of time so I can easily debug constructed result.
- Preferred solution is in same task and also easily readable.

**EDIT**: Based in @Zeitounator [gist](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/0725f6006101e28a5edd889f8132632e) I ended up with this.

```
---
- name: >
    LISTDELETED {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_DATABASE }} databases
    FROM {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_SQLSERVER }} sqlserver
  vars:
    listdelted_command: >
      az sql db list-deleted
      --resource-group "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESOURCEGROUP }}"
      --server "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_SQLSERVER }}"
      {% if DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY is defined %}
      --query "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY }}"
      {% endif %}
  command: "{{ listdelted_command }}"
  register: DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESULT
```

Comment: I was thinking about ternary operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requirements 2 and 3 are mutually exclusive: you can build a var ahead of time (e.g. prior to executing the ansible module) in a task but it will be available only to this task (see the rescue task for an illustration in my example below).

[`default`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) filter as you used it will let you handle a default value for a specific unset variable. If you want to omit a more complex string, you will have to surround it with an `if` jinja2 expression using the relevant test.

This is what I would try in your case (not fully tested because I don't have `az` installed and therefore no db/query to run against)

```
- name: Store my command in a var
  set_fact:
    my_command: >-
      az sql db list-deleted
      --resource-group "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESOURCEGROUP }}"
      --server "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_SQLSERVER }}"
      {% if DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY is defined %}
      --query "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY }}"
      {% if %}
      --output json

- block:
    - name: >
        LISTDELETED {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_DATABASE }} databases
        FROM {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_SQLSERVER }} sqlserver
      command: "{{ my_command }}"
      register: DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESULT
  rescue:
    - name: debug failed az command
      var:
        msg: |
          There as been an error running the following command:
          {{ my_command }}
          The reported error was:
          {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESULT.stderr }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
```

Notes:

- [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) will store the mentionned variable as a fact for the current host. You can then reuse this variable for the same host in other tasks.
- I used a [`block`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) with a [`rescue`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks-error-handling) to illustrate conditional debugging. Modify to your needs.
- The `-` sign on the yaml folded block is the [strip chomping indicator](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2794534) to make sure the new lines in the code introduced for readability are not interfering with the constructed command.
- `msg.split('\n')` in the debug task is simply turning the multi-line message string into a list for an easier screen readability.
- If your variable `DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY` can be set with an empty string and you also want to handle that case to skip the `--query` parameter, you can change the test to `DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY | default() | length > 0`

Comment: {% if DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY is defined %} does not seem to work inlined like this. Also - maybe pointless since > expands nelines to space.

Comment: @johnymachine: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/0725f6006101e28a5edd889f8132632e. Unless I totally missed your point, this is plainly answering your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Jinja2 template for this, where you can use if-else to include some parts of command e.g --query

```
---
- name: >
    LISTDELETED {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_DATABASE }} databases
    FROM {{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_SQLSERVER }} sqlserver
  command: >
    az sql db list-deleted
    --resource-group "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESOURCEGROUP }}"
    --server "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_SQLSERVER }}"
{% if DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY %}
    --query "{{ DATABASE_LISTDELETED_QUERY | default('[*]') }}"
{% endif %}
    --output json
  register: DATABASE_LISTDELETED_RESULT
```

Then parse it using ansible template module

```
- name: Template a file to my-command.yml
  template:
    src: /mytemplates/foo.j2
    dest: /commands/my-command.yml
```